# Как удалить cookie после второй перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: php, javascript, cookie

К примеру:

после заполнения формы страница перезагружается и появляется alert с уведомлением что форма успешно отправлена. текст в alert это cookie с текстом.

```
$_COOKIE['alert'] = "Ваша заявка успешно отправлена";
```

Вопрос:

как удалить cookie после следующей перезагрузке страницы?

Comment: выводи и сразу очищай.

Comment: Не ставить куки? Ведь их смысл в том, чтобы сохранять информацию между перезагрузками страницы. Один раз выводить надо генерацией страницы.

Comment: пытаюсь добиться результата, одноразового уведомления

Answer (score 1):

Для одного вывода не нужно использовать куки.
К примеру, после обработки заявки и её успешного размещения, генерируем вывод шаблона вида "Успех, принято" и... всё!
Следующие загрузки не будут создавать заявку и движок не будет генерировать этот шаблон.

UPD:

На пальцах:

```
Вы ----> Сервер
         Обработка заказа
         Генерация страницы с сообщением "Успех, принято"
Вы <---- Код страницы
```

Comment: дело в том что после отправки формы страница полностью перезагружается и идет полный сброс данных с $_POST и приходиться все сохранять в cookie

Comment: Обновил........